# Why do FusionTable layers sometimes not work / slow down?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Fusion tables layers are great.  I have uploaded some data and polygons of areas in Europe and most of the time they respond very fast.

First thing in the morning (after prolonged inactivity I assume), the layer will sometimes take some time (about 5 minutes) before it appears.

Occasionally (about once a day), even whilst I am looking at and using the map layer, it drastically slows down, or stops working all together.  This lasts for roughly half an hour.

Are these common and unavoidable problem of using a service I neither control nor paid for, or is there something I might have done wrong?  Is anyone else experiencing issues?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an issue that Google will have to address. I recommend searching/posting here: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!categories/google-fusion-tables/broken